# Username suggestion in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to create a function in php to suggest usernames, if the entered username is not available.
For example, username entered is 'bingo' and it not available, then the system should suggest a list of usernames like this

```
bi_n_go
go-nbi
b-n_gio
b-ng-oi
...
```

Rules for creating username are :

- minimum length 6
- username can contain maximum 3 symbols(only hyphens, underscores)
- username must start with alphanumeric and end with alphanumeric

Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: @Deepu: I tried str_shuffle with some regex i got from some forums, but i can't achieve what i need :(. Do you have any suggestions.. ?

Comment: Do you think using usernames like `bing_o`, `b_ing_o`, `bi_ng_o` will help distinguishing them?

Comment: Minimun length - `6`, maximum - `3`. Great!

Comment: @Jari : it is maximum 3 symbols, not username length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code:

```
<?php
//mutates given user name, producing possibly incorrect username
function mutate($uname)
{
    $x = str_split($uname);

    //sort with custom function, that tries to produce only slightly
    //random user name (as opposed to completely shuffling)
    uksort($x, function($a, $b)
    {
        $chance = mt_rand(0, 3);
        if ($chance == 0)
        {
            return $b - $a;
        }
        return $a - $b;
    });

    //insert randomly dashes and underscores
    //(multiplication for getting more often 0 than 3)
    $chance = mt_rand(0, 3) * mt_rand(0, 3) / 3.;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $chance; $i ++)
    {
        $symbol = mt_rand() & 1 ? '-' : '_';
        $pos = mt_rand(0, count($x));
        array_splice($x, $pos, 0, $symbol);
    }
    return join('', $x);
}

//validates the output so you can check whether new user name is correct
function validate($uname)
{
    //does not start nor end with alphanumeric characters
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9].*[a-zA-Z0-9]$/', $uname))
    {
        return false;
    }
    //does contain more than 3 symbols
    $noSymbols = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '', $uname);
    if (strlen($uname) - strlen($noSymbols) > 3)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //shorter than 6 characters
    if (strlen($uname) < 6)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$uname = 'bingo';
$desired_num = 5;
$sug = [];
while (count($sug) < $desired_num)
{
    $mut = mutate($uname);
    if (!validate($mut))
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (!in_array($mut, $sug) and $mut != $uname)
    {
        $sug []= $mut;
    }
}
print_r($sug);
```

Example output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => i-g-obn
    [1] => bi-gno
    [2] => bi_ngo
    [3] => i-bnog
    [4] => bign-o
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my created function .
I hope it will help you

```
echo stringGenerator("bingo");
function stringGenerator($str)
{
$middleStr = $str."-_";
$first = $str[rand(0, strlen($str)-1)];
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
    $middle .= $middleStr[rand(0, strlen($middleStr))];
}
$last = $str[rand(0, strlen($str)-1)];

return $first.$middle.$last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking through PHP and Mysql you can suggest the user by shuffling the user's input:

```
$str = 'abcdef';
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++){
$shuffled = str_shuffle($str).'</br>';
echo $shuffled;
}
```

Output:

```
   bfdcea
   cdfbae
   adefcb
   beacfd
```